# strange behaviour of pyplotlib upper menubar

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am willing to integrate a matplotlib figure into a GUI designed with pyqt5:
I wrote the code above:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):



        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1056, 600)
        self.vbox2 = MainWindow.layout()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEdit_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 430, 40, 20))
        self.lineEdit_x.setObjectName("lineEdit_x")
        self.lineEdit_x.setText(str(1))
        self.lineEdit_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_y.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(595, 430, 40, 20))
        self.lineEdit_y.setObjectName("lineEdit_y")
        self.lineEdit_y.setText(str(1))
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 430, 66, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.figure = plt.figure()#figsize=(40, 10), dpi=18)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        #self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.on_release)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_press)
        self.canvas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,30, 400, 400))

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas,  self)
        self.vbox2.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.vbox2.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.plot()




        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1056, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def plot(self):
        data = [random.random() for i in range(23)]
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data, 'r-', linewidth=0.5)
        ax.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        self.canvas.draw()
    def on_press(self, event):
        self.lineEdit_x.setText(str(event.x))
        self.lineEdit_y.setText(str(event.y))

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Center (x,y)"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

as one can see I have 2 issues:

1. the menu bar is detached from the figure and reduced
2. the axes are smaller than the figure field.
   so can someone please check my code to address these two issues **with minimum modifications**
   thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as "address these issues with minimum modifications", especially considering that your code has ***a lot*** of issues, and the two that you're pointing out are just the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code, and most of them are caused by the fact that you're editing a pyuic file, which is considered a *bad* practice, and one of the many reasons of that consideration is that the class pyuic provides is often being used in the wrong way, like in this case.

First of all, you're creating instances for both `QMainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow`, which already inherits from QMainWindow, so the first one is completely pointless.

Then, you're trying to access the main window layout, but that's also wrong, as QMainWindow has *its own* private layout. The only proper way to add widgets to a main window is using the provided API, and, in your case:

- [`setCentralWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) to set the *central widget*, which is the main content of the window, and set its layout to which the actual widgets are being added;
- [`addToolBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBar) to add tool bars;

So, this is a proper rewriting of your expected result.

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1056, 600)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Center (x,y)')

        self.lineEdit_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_x.setText(str(1))

        self.lineEdit_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_y.setText(str(1))

        central = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        bottomLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(bottomLayout)
        bottomLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        bottomLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_x)
        bottomLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_y)

        self.plot()


    def plot(self):
        data = [random.random() for i in range(23)]
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data, 'r-', linewidth=0.5)
        ax.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.lineEdit_x.setText(str(event.x))
        self.lineEdit_y.setText(str(event.y))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that if you still want to use Designer, then keep in mind that:

- as said above, you should *not* edit the pyuic generated file (but, instead, follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);
- add the canvas by code, or use a promoted widget (do some research on the subject);
- always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) for *all* widgets;

Comment: I appreciate your educative comment and answer. thank you very much.
I just followed some high-ranked youtube videos that provided this pyuic-based strategy.
thank you

Comment: @yuri There is absolutely *nothing* wrong in using the pyuic approach. But you must use it properly. I sincerely hope that the tutorial you followed didn't suggest to edit the pyuic file or use the main window private layout. If, instead, it actually proposed to do so: 1. completely ignore that tutorial and remove from your memory anything you learnt from it; 2. please provide me the link, as I'm going to put it on my list of "this is not a tutorial, it's just sh*t" that I will always suggest to completely avoid (like the infamous PyQt tutorial of a "Code First with Hala").

Comment: it is most likely that I miss understood the tutorial. At min 10:00 from PyQT5 Designer Drag and Drop GUI - PyQt5 GUI Thursdays #6 the developer started to modify the generated .py file I adopt his Ideas wrongly. I am learning he and for sure you are the profis in this field. I would be glad if you suggest to me a book about GUI implementation in python
THX

Comment: @yuri Thanks for that link. It's not your fault, by the way: while that tutorial seems to generally provide good knowledge, it's completely wrong on that point (and they reiterate the concept in various comments, providing terrible suggestions). I've already added a couple of comments there. As written in my answer, you *can* use pyuic files, but you have to use them properly (and not edit them). Read that "using Designer" link and you'll find out how you can properly use those files without risking unnecessary headaches (I generally suggest the "multiple inheritance" method).